# Passing compiled parameter to directive for ng-click

Tags: angularjs, handlebars.js, mustache

I'm trying to use ng-repeat in Angular 1.6.x

`getToggle` keys returns `['card1', 'card2']`

```
<li ng-repeat="fi in getToggleKeys()">
     <a ng-click="actions.toggleMode($event, '{{fi}}')" href="#"</a>
</li>


actions: {
    toggleFIMode(event, mode) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.getMode = mode;
},
```

**Problem:**

- When the DOM renders, I see the proper value for `{{fi}}` as `card1` **however, when the function toggleFIMode is being called, I see `{{fi}}` instead of card.** as second param.

Can someone enlighten me what I'm doing wrong?

How can I send compiled version of the `{{fi}}` to the function?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `{{}}`, `ngClick` already expects an Angular expression:

```
<a ng-click="actions.toggleMode($event, fi)" href="#"</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Strange but it works. I see `<a ng-click="actions.toggleMode($event, fi)" href="#"</a>` on DOM (I was expecting the value of `fi` to be replaced)

Comment: I don't think the DOM will render the evaluated string of `fi` - but it will be called with the correct value.